# What user account info should you encrypt and what to encode and what to leave as is?

Tags: html, database, security, account

When you deal with account info, how secure should each data item be?

I'm going to do three categories and list items under them, please tell me if I'm right/wrong:

**Encrypt:**
password

**Encode:**
email,
address,
paypal,
secret_answer,

**Leave as is:**
everything else

Django encrypts the password automatically, or is this hashing? What's the difference between hashing and encrypting?

I know encoding doesn't add security, but it's better than a hacker just looking at the info right? Like if the hacker does bother with decoding the info, does the time bought to inform the users of the breach outweigh the bother of encoding the info?

If I use `hashlib.sha1`, is `sha1(sh1+sha1)` safe enough?

Comment: I think you seem to mix up some terms. I think “encrypt” meant to be [hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) and “encode” meant to be [encrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

encode doesn't add any security.

Encrypt password is never good, you're never free of lossing the key or something like that.

You should Hash the password using salt (just search some questions about it in stackoverflow and you'll find good points about it).

Email, address: maybe encrypt, depends if you want it to be searchable inside your database

Paypal: what do you mean with it? just an email for login? encrypt.

secret_answer is just like a password, so use the same approach.

Edit: encoding, obfuscation, saving the string backwards, using ROT-3 cryptography is even worst than using none: with none you know you don't have security, with this silly "protections" you'll fool yourself that you have security, and will relax on other securities.

Comment: django automatically encrypts password

Comment: i know encoding doesn't add security, but it still prevents a hacker from just looking at the info

Comment: 2 - if someone breaks inside your system, "encoding" is something he might have learnt in the "101 hacking class".

Comment: yea i'm starting to think encoding is kind of worthless too, but in the case there's a breach, and the info u can't really hash/encrypt, wat can u do to protect it?

Comment: like for email, I need to put the email data in and then read it to display it on the user's account info, how would I protect this data in the database?

Comment: it email isn't a key where you do searches on, you can encrypt it.

Comment: sorry I such a newb at this, but there's hashing, encrypting, and encoding right? hashing is not reversable(sha1), encrypting(AES) is, and then what is encoding?

Comment: Encoding is used to replace unsafe characters in string with safe characters (like `&gt;` rather than `>`).  Proper encoding of strings is one of the ways to protect against XSS.

Comment: @Derek: take a look at wikipedia about encoding. For example, [base64 encoding is use to trasmit binary data where just textual data was expected] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)